# Laravel multiple queue:listen ignores timeout / starts again

Tags: php, laravel, queue, supervisord, forge

So this seems to be a weird issue, we have a process that sends out 5.000 or 10.000 emails in 1 job, but it keeps starting every 60 seconds even if the other process is still running.

As deamon command:

```
queue:work database --sleep=10 --daemon --quiet --tries=3 --env=production --queue="default"
```

As listen command:

```
queue:listen database --timeout=600 --sleep=10 --quiet --tries=3 --env=production --queue="emails"
```

The thing that happens here if we run multiple listeners or multiple worker deamons after aprox 60 seconds a new process will start all over again, it feels like a php timeout, but the other process will just continu so it seems to start a new one for no reason. In the code it will loop, getting 100 emails from the DB everytime and write to a log file

```
\Log::info("Getting {$emails->count()} new e-mails, round: {$this->round}
```

Log file:

```
[2015-11-09 13:02:27] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 1
[2015-11-09 13:02:32] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 2
[2015-11-09 13:02:38] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 3
[2015-11-09 13:02:43] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 4
[2015-11-09 13:02:49] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 5
[2015-11-09 13:02:55] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 6
[2015-11-09 13:03:00] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 7
[2015-11-09 13:03:06] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 8
[2015-11-09 13:03:11] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 9
[2015-11-09 13:03:17] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 10
[2015-11-09 13:03:22] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 11
[2015-11-09 13:03:28] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 12
[2015-11-09 13:03:32] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 1
[2015-11-09 13:03:35] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 13
[2015-11-09 13:03:42] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 2
[2015-11-09 13:03:45] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 14
[2015-11-09 13:03:52] production.INFO: Getting 100 new e-mails, round: 3
```

Here you can see that the old process continues and a new one starts so it sends double emails. When starting a new process the jobs table updates the attempts to 1 and reserved_at is also updated.

Can anyone help me here, it must be something stupid but we tried almost everything and it keeps running multiple times. Running 1 queue deamon worker or queue listen solves the problem but we want to run multiple queue workers on one queue which should be possible.

We run on forge that spawns the processes with supervisord

Comment: Figured out its because of the TTR (Time-To-Run) in Laravel which is 60 seconds and can be configured in the queue.php config, still looking for a solution to set the TTR on a per job basis instead of overall.

Comment: I would make a seperate queue for just this job and handle it with just one listener/workers, it's as simple as adding a new queue to the connections array in the queue config. It's really just a logical seperation if you are using the same driver for both queues and should solve this problem for you. You can then add another general purpose queue to the array and run multiple listeners against that for other types of jobs.